# codeigniter join same table multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i need some codeigniter 3 help from you friends. its like 10 years ago when i did some more complex querys and my noobish JOIN-trys just gave me errors and questionmarks for hours.

lets say i have a mysql table covers

```
id, text, bgcolor_id, color_id
example : 1, "nice headline", 55, 88
```

and a table colors

```
id, value, name
example : 55, #FF0000, "red"
example : 88, #000000, "black"
```

how to "link" based on bgcolor_id, color_id in table covers

```
cover.bgcolor_id -> 
color.value AS bgcolorvalue
color.name AS bgcolorname

cover.color_id ->
color.value AS colorvalue
color.name AS colorname
```

my codeigniter model

```
public function list(){
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM covers ORDER BY id DESC');
return $query->result_array();
}

public function get($id){
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM covers WHERE id = ' . $id);
return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Join twice your colors table

```
select c.*,c1.name bgcolorname,
c1.value bgcolorvalue,
c2.name colorname, 
c2.value colorvalue
from covers c
join colors c1 on c.bgcolor_id = c1.id
join colors c2 on c.color_id = c2.id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd07b9d/2)

Comment: oh dude. men. im impressed - it works. i try to understand your query so hard, my brain is already smoking. now i think if i try to recreate this in "active records style" from codeigniter... hope i will get it after sleeping...

Comment: @scco yup give it a try with active record if you are unable to accomplish this then let me know i will add the active record version also

Comment: hey m khalid junaid, do you know how i could advance your sql solution : when somebody deletes the color row so there is no id - the complete query  will not appear or give errors.  so is there a way to just "optional" join the colors when there ARE colors - otherwise just have empty fields ?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use the query builder [Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

You could to something like.

```
$cv = 'covers';
        $cl1 = 'colors';
        $cl2 = 'colors';
        $get = array(
            $cv.'.id',
            $cv.'.text',
            $cv.'.bgcolor_id',
            $cv.'.color_id',
            $cl1.'.value as bgcolorvalue',
            $cl1.'.name as bgcolorname',
            $cl1.'.value as colorvalue',
            $cl1.'.name as colorname'
        );
        $this->db->select($get);
        $this->db->from($cv);
        $this->db->where($cv.'.id', 1);
        $this->db->join($cl1, $cv.'.bgcolor_id = ' . $cl1.'.id');
        $this->db->join($cl2, $cv.'.color_id = ' . $cl2.'.id');
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();
```

let me know if this works

Comment: hey hey exe - cause you wana know if it works - it produces :

Not unique table/alias: 'colors'

SELECT `covers`.`id`, `covers`.`text`, `covers`.`bgcolor_id`, `covers`.`color_id`, `colors`.`value` as `bgcolorvalue`, `colors`.`name` as `bgcolorname`, `colors`.`value` as `colorvalue`, `colors`.`name` as `colorname` FROM `covers` JOIN `colors` ON `covers`.`bgcolor_id` = `colors`.`id` JOIN `colors` ON `covers`.`color_id` = `colors`.`id` WHERE `covers`.`id` = 1

Answer (score 0):

As i have understood your question right then you want to join on `colors` table twice for `bgcolor_id` and `color_id`, so here i am providing solution for your question let me know if it works or something wrong with the solutuion, thanks.

```
 public function list(){
     $query = $this->db->select("covers.*, bg.value AS bgcolorvalue bg.name AS 
                            bgcolorname, colors.value AS colorvalue
                            colors.name AS colorname")
                 ->join("colors", "colors.id = covers.color_id", "left")
                 ->join("colors as bg", "bg.id = covers.bgcolor_id", "left")
                 ->get("covers")->result(); 
     return $query->result_array();
 }
```